# How to use a image in parent component when the image is from child component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

I created an image in child component (I think that is called child component, sorry if I am wrong). I want to use that image in parent component but I don't know how to do it properly and got error message of 'finaleImg' is not defined.

```
function App() {

  const dragUrl = React.useRef();
  const stageRef = React.useRef();

  const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
  const onSuccess = (savedFiles) => {
    setFiles(savedFiles)
  };


  const DropDownMenu = ({ files }) => {

    console.log("files", files)

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      setValue(event.target.value);
      //console.log("handleChange", event.target.value)
      dragUrl.current = `//localhost:5000/${event.target.value}`;
      console.log("dragurl", dragUrl.current)


    };

    const [finaleImg] = useImage(dragUrl.current); 
    console.log("finaleImg", finaleImg)


    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Choose Floor
          <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
            {files.map((file, i) => (
              <option
                key={i}
                value={file.src}>{file.filename}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>

        {/*<p>Floor!</p>*/}
      </div>
    );

  }


  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div className='fileUploader'>
        <FileUploader onSuccess={onSuccess} />
      </div>

      <div className='uploaded-images'>
        {/*<Preview files={files} />*/}
        <DropDownMenu files={files} />
      </div>

      <div className='stage'>

        <div>

          <br />

          { /*<Preview files={files} />*/}

          <div

          >

            <Stage

              width={window.innerWidth}
              height={window.innerHeight}

              /*width= "1500"
              height = "1500"*/
              style={{ border: '1px solid grey' }}
              ref={stageRef}

            >
              <Layer>
                <Rect
                  width={window.innerWidth}
                  height={window.innerHeight}
                  fill="red"

                //fillPatternImage={finaleImg}

                />
              </Layer>
            </Stage>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

With `const [finaleImg] = useImage(dragUrl.current);` I created the image in DropDownMenu function and I can see it in the console between img tags. But I need to use it in the `//fillPatternImage={finaleImg}` where that line is placed in return of App function. How can I use it?

This is what I got when I uncommented the line `//fillPatternImage={finaleImg}`:
[image: uncommented]

And this is what I got when it is commented, I wanted to show you finaleImg is working:
[image: commented]

Comment: In general: if you want to use a state in more than one component, put it in the common parent (or if one is the child of the other, in the parent).

Comment: Why do you create it in the child when you want to use it in the parent and you don't use it in the child?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I got the url of image from a drop down menu and when I choose something else from the menu, the url updates too.

Comment: @ChrisG It didn't work or I couldn't do it. But when I defined it on top, it gets the first item on the menu and does not change.